# Angular Slickgrid - Load singleselect editor collection based on grid data

Tags: angular, inline-editing, angular-slickgrid

I am working on the angular-slickgrid(2.18.7) where the grid has inline singleselect dropdown editor. I want to display the dropdown values based on table data of each row item.

```
{
      id: 'status', name: 'Status', field: 'status',
      sortable: true,
      filterable: true,
      editor: {
        model: Editors.singleSelect,
        collection: // dynamic collection items,
      }
}
```

the `first` row of `status:'odd'` column `editor.collection` values are,

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>
```

the `second` row of `status:'even'` column `editor.collection` values are,

```
<select>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
</select>
```

I have to populate the `editor.collection` values dynamically based on the value of `status` column of each row item.

Is there a way to make a callback function to set the `editor.collection` dynamically?

It would be grateful if someone helps on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `collectionAsync` as demoed in the [Example - Client](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/clientside) and see the [code](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/examples/grid-clientside.component.ts#L80) and the [Wiki - Select Filter with CollectionAsync](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Select-Filter#collection-async-load). There's a lot of info in the Wikis, I suggest you to go through them.

To filter the `collection` you can use `filterBy` as documented in the [Wiki - collection-filterby/sortby](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Select-Filter#collection-filterbysortby) but you **cannot** filter dynamically (afterward) because it must be set only once, you might be able to push a new collection by using `collectionAsync` but it's not ideal, it wasn't meant for that intent. The other possibility might be to use the `Filters.autoComplete`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think, you misunderstood.. I was asking about the `editor.collection` not grid filters. updated  my question for better understanding..